# How to programmatically set focus on input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I'm try to programmatically set focus on an input but for some reason, my code won't work. Hopefully someone is able to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    inputRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>()

    focusInput = ()=> {
       const node = this.inputRef.current

       if(node) {
         console.log(node) // <input type="number" value />
         node.focus() // However focus is not set on the input
       }
    }

    getInputRef = ()=> {
       return this.inputRef
    }

    render(){
       return <ChildComponent getInputRef={this.getInputRef} focusInput={this.focusInput} />
    }
}

const ChildComponent: React.FC<any> = ({getInputRef, focusInput})=> (
   <React.Fragment>
       <input 
         type="number"
         ref={()=>getInputRef()}
       />
       <button onClick={()=>focusInput()}>Set Focus</button>
   </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: Is your expectation that the input would focus itself as soon as the component is mounted?

Comment: Actually, the input should focus upon clicking a button. I have updated my post.

Comment: Just wrote you a solution! Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `React.forwardRef` to pass a `ref` defined in a Parent Component to a functional Child Component. Try something like this:

**Parent**

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  inputRef = React.createRef();

  focusInput = () => {
    const node = this.inputRef.current;
    if (node) {
      node.focus();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <ChildComponent ref={this.inputRef} focusInput={this.focusInput} />;
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={ref} />
      <button onClick={() => props.focusInput()}>Set Focus</button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Here's a sandbox for your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactforwardref-o1jtt